# Set state is not re-rendering component in React / ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the following component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './ShareModal.css';
import { observer } from 'mobx-react';

// Components
import Modal from '../Modal/Modal';
import Button from '../Button/Button';
import Input from '../Input/Input';

// Stores
import UiStore from '../../stores/UiStore';

@observer
class ShareModal extends React.Component {

    constructor () {

        super();
        this.state = {
            inputs : [
                { type: 'email', placeholder: 'Email Address' }
            ]
        };

    }

    addInput () {

        // DEBUG
        console.log('Adding an input...');

        // this.state.inputs = this.state.inputs.concat([
        //     { type: 'email', placeholder: 'Email Address' }
        // ]);

        this.setState(this.state.inputs.concat([
            { type: 'email', placeholder: 'Email Address' }
        ]));

    }

    render () {

        return (
            <div className={ UiStore.state.shareVisible ? styles.visible : styles.hidden }>

                <Modal id={'share'}>

                    <div className={styles.content}>

                        <h1 className={styles.title}>Share</h1>

                        <p className={styles.description}>Share with as many friends as you want. Add their email addressess below</p>

                        {
                            // Itterates over all inputs in the current state
                            this.state.inputs.map((item, i) => (
                                <Input key={i} type={item.type} placeholder={item.placeholder} />
                            ))
                        }

                        <Button
                            icon = {'add'}
                            color = {'#FC3839'}
                            type = {'outline'}
                            text = {'Add Another Email Address'}
                            width = {'full'}
                            rounded = {false}
                            action = {this.addInput.bind(this)}
                        />

                        <Button
                            color = {'#FC3839'}
                            type = {'full'}
                            text = {'Share'}
                            width = {'full'}
                            rounded = {true}
                        />

                    </div>

                </Modal>

            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ShareModal;
```

I'm stuck on the `addInput` function. You can probably gather what's supposed to happen when that function runs... So on the button click it runs (which it does) and then should add another input in `this.state.inputs` but it doesn't seem to be working. Also no errors are showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know mobx, but shouldn't it be:

```
    this.setState({ 
        inputs: this.state.inputs.concat([
            { type: 'email', placeholder: 'Email Address' }
        ])
    });
```

Comment: yeah the state should be an object, OP's code tries to set it to an array

Answer (score 1):

Small change and it will work.  You need to set the state with an object.  `Array.concat` returns an array.

```
this.setState({inputs: this.state.inputs.concat([
  { type: 'email', placeholder: 'Email Address' }
])});
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous):

> React may batch multiple `setState()` calls into a single update for
>   performance.
>
> Because `this.props` and `this.state` may be updated asynchronously, you
>   should not rely on their values for calculating the next state.

I prefer doing it this way:

```
this.setState((prevState) => ({
  inputs: prevState.concat([
    { type: 'email', placeholder: 'Email Address' }
  ])
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

this.setState accepts an object ..try passing an object